# Public download for javax.media.jai classes?

Tags: java, jai

This is a pretty simple question... I've been looking for where you can download the javax.media.jai.* libraries. I found the jai imageio libraries... but all the rest of the jai stuff I find is either pretty out of date ( 2008 and before ) and I run into a login screen...

Is there a public download for the javax.media.jai stuff anywhere?

Thanks for any help in making up for my not so good google-fu on this one...

Comment: download links are posted in thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/21752082/1498669

Comment: Currently, it is at https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-client-downloads.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Download](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html) and [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/jaifaq-138288.html) for more info.

Maven users should refer to the [Using Java Advanced Imaging with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1209583/181497) question.

Comment: thank you. i spent the entire afternoon and never found either of these.

Answer (score 0):

Current download page is [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html).

You can also find Maven repository at [here](http://mavenhub.com/mvn/thirdparty-releases/javax.media/jai-core/1.1.3).