# Java Advanced Imaging - where to get latest binary build?

Tags: java, binary, download, jai

I am searching for the latest official binary builds of Java Advanced Imaging (at least the platform independent Java-only build).

The official project web page is on http://java.net/projects/jai-core/ but it only links to the source - binary builds are not mentioned - or am I too blind to see them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Public download for javax.media.jai classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999491/public-download-for-javax-media-jai-classes)

Comment: Well if one of three URLs does not work does not mean the answer is outdated.

Comment: your link does contain the lib and the native libs - just walk down to https://java.net/projects/jai-core/sources/svn/show/trunk/src/share/mediaLib/ but the full libs are posted at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21752082/1498669

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are referring to the wrong site...the correct site is as follows:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html

Edited: ok, this is strange...last time I did see a JAI package which I used to test JAI features in JUNG 2.0 Framework...I remembered I downloaded it from somewhere from the link above...

Well, I've googled it: get JAI 1.1.3 from here...

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaicore113jar.htm

Comment: Thanks for finding the "read thread" into the center of the JAI maze...

Comment: the ImageIO builds for JAI are at http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/builds/release/1.1/

Comment: All Oracle's JAI downloads [are located here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/current-142188.html).

Comment: These links are now 404s.

Comment: yeah all I get are 404s, how am I suppose to download this?

Comment: I found the valid download link: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaicore113jar.htm

Comment: @craigds Try http://data.opengeo.org/suite/jai/ as supposed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502181/where-can-i-download-jai-and-jai-imageio

Comment: ImageIO at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/j/Downloadjaiimageio11jar.htm