# Where can I download Jai and Jai-imageio?

Tags: java, jai

I need to get the pixel color of a `TIFF` image, if you know any alternatives to `Jai` and `Jai-imageio` please let me know.

Comment: Partially true, but I need these libraries for programming though and I figured that here I could find some help. Also, I'm asking for programming alternatives for what I have to do: getting pixel color from TIFF without using Jai and Jai-imageio.

Comment: If you are just looking for the .jar file necessary to decode JPEG 2000 and friends with `ImageIO` and don't want to bother with any installers, download http://mapgrid.googlecode.com/files/jai_imageio.jar

Comment: as always -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/21752082/1498669

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Here you go: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html

Maybe this is interessting, too. I saw they provide some extensions:
http://java.net/projects/imageio

I know about [Sanselan](http://commons.apache.org/sanselan/index.html) and [ImageJ](http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/), too, but do not know
if and how they give you the ability to read the pixelcolor.

But as long as you can get a `BufferedImage` in Java you should
be able to do what is needed.

Comment: Thanks, how do I get to download imageio from your second link?

Comment: On the first look, I do not see one. But I think it should be easy to build a jar file with ant. See the build.xml in the Subversion trunk.

Comment: 2013 update: https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases/javax/media/jai-core/
http://maven.geotoolkit.org/javax/media/jai_imageio/1.1/

Comment: The imageio-ext project moved to github: https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext/

Comment: Here's a project on Git which is a clone of JAI ImageIO Core but where dependencies to jai-core (javax.media.jai) and JPEG 2000 (jj2000) have been removed. The readme says that it is fully redistributable under the 3-clause BSD license in LICENSE.txt (and thus is GPL compatible): https://github.com/stain/jai-imageio-core

Comment: As of 2015-07-17, the download links of the page provided by this answer are dead. Please see my update on the question.

Comment: @zeodtr As JAI seems to have been removed by Oracle, I just want to mention that I have created a project that in many cases can be used as a replacement for JAI (the *JAI ImageIO* part). It does, among quite a few other formats, read [TIFF](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#aldusadobe-tagged-image-file-format-tiff). It works the same way as `jai_imageio.jar`, by providing plugins for `ImageIO` (ie. a completely familiar API).

Comment: @haraldK Thanks. But I'm using GeoServer which still uses JAI. It would be nice if GeoServer replaces its use of JAI with a more modern library, like yours.

Comment: @haraldK please provide the link to download your jars...Thanks in advance

Comment: @SumitKumarSaha It's the same link as above, just scroll a bit further down the page, or search for [Links to prebuilt binaries](http://haraldk.github.io/TwelveMonkeys/#links-to-prebuilt-binaries). I highly recommend using Maven, Gradle or other project/dependency management tool though, rather than downloading directly.

Comment: Thanks @haraldK , looking forward to use twelvemonkeysIO in my project