# Save a BufferedImage as a TIFF file?

Tags: java, image, tiff

The following code works fine to write a `BufferedImage` to a file in .bmp, .jpg and .png formats:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
...
BufferedImage image; // assume `image` is properly initialized
File file; // assume 'file' is properly initialized to some file
String format; // This is either 'bmp', 'jpg', or 'png'; if 'tif', it fails
ImageIO.write(imageBlank, format, file); // This properly creates a file for 'bmp', 'jpg', or 'png'; not for 'tif'
```

However, when the format is .tif, the above code throws an exception on the `write` line.

Many links suggest using the Java Advanced Imaging API to create TIFF's; some give the following link: http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jai/.  However, this link does not lead to a download of JAI.  Other links are either dead or circular.  I don't think that JAI is included with JDK 1.7; am I correct?

Can someone either give a working link to the actual JAI download, or else tell me how to create a .tif file from a `BufferedImage` using JDK 1.7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This project apparently adds TIFF read and write capabilities to ImageIO: http://java.net/projects/imageio-ext

If you are looking for JAI 1.1.3: [Where can I download Jai and Jai-imageio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502181/where-can-i-download-jai-and-jai-imageio)

Comment: Imageio-ext moved to: [https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/imageio-ext)

Comment: This is not satisfactory answer, provide some solution to specific problem instead of illustrating tools and libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the download page for JAI.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#jai-1_1_2_01-oth-JPR