# Resizing .tif image with imgscalr

Tags: resize, base64, tiff, javax.imageio, imgscalr

I am trying to resize a .tif image and then display it on the browser by converting it to a base64 string. Since ImageIo doesn't support TIF images by default, i have added imageio_alpha-1.1.jar(got it here - http://www.findjar.com/jar/geoserver/jai/jars/jai_imageio-1.1-alpha.jar.html). Now ImageIO is able to register the plugin, which i checked by doing this

String[] writerNames = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();

writerNames has TIF in it, this means ImageIO has registered the plugin.

I am resizing the image like this

```
Map resizeImage(BufferedImage imageData, int width, int height, String imageFormat){

                BufferedImage thumbnail =  Scalr.resize(imageData, Scalr.Method.SPEED, Scalr.Mode.FIT_EXACT ,
                    width, height, Scalr.OP_ANTIALIAS);

                String[] writerNames = ImageIO.getWriterFormatNames();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
                ImageIO.write(thumbnail, imageFormat, baos)
                baos.flush()
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray()
                baos.close()

                return [imageBytes:imageBytes, imageFormat:imageFormat]
            }

    String encodeImageToBase64(byte[] imageData){
                return Base64.encodeBase64String(imageData)
            }

BufferedImage getBufferedImage(byte[] imageData){
                ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData)
                BufferedImage bImageFromConvert = ImageIO.read(bais)
                bais.close()
                return bImageFromConvert
            }

String resizeToDimensions(byte[] imageData, String imageFormat, int width, int height){
            def  bimg = getBufferedImage(imageData)
            Map resizedImageData = resizeImage(bimg, width, height, imageFormat)
            return encodeImageToBase64(resizedImageData.imageBytes)
        }
```

now i am displaying the image like this
 `< img src = "data:image/tif;base64,TU0AKgAAAAgADAEAAAMAAA...." />` with this i get failed to load url message(on hovering)
as far as i know the  base64 string usually starts with /9j/(may be i am wrong). when i am appending /9j/. I get an error - "image corrupt or truncated". I am not able to figure out the problem here, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance your use of the [Data URI format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#Format) looks correct -- try and narrow down exactly where the failure is.

I would recommend:

1. In your method where you return the string to the front end, I would recommend printing the entire thing out to the console to get the raw data in Data URI format.
2. Take the Data URI string, create a sample HTML file with the hard-coded value in it, try and load it... does the image display? If so, great, then your problem is with how you are streaming that back to the front end or how you are trying to load it. (Likely a JavaScript/DOM issue)
3. If that doesn't work, try and chop the Base64 section out of the example and save it into an example TXT file. In your Java code, load it, decode it and try and create an image out of it and write it back out to a TIFF -- if that didn't work, then there is something wrong with your Base64 handling and the encoding is invalid most likely.

Getting that far should answer most of the questions.

Actually now that I think about it, try and use ImageIO to read the image into a BufferedImage, then process it with imgscalr, then immediately call ImageIO.write and try and write it out to a new TIF someplace else and make sure the ImageIO decoding/encoding process is working correctly.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for replying Riyad, There is something interesting i noticed, i just tried encoding the byte array containing the image to a base64 string, and it is displaying properly in the browser, so problem seems to be with the scaling(and i think problem is with the jai_imageio-alpha-1.1.jar). I just found this jar when i was searching for the class com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageWriterSpi. I tried the jar specified in this stackoverflow post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502181/where-can-i-download-jai-and-jai-imageio. But it doesn't seem to provide the desired class

Comment: I think if i get the proper plugin jar it would work, because the problem is not with imgscalr, it seems to be with ImageIO, anyways i will try out your suggestions, and post back the result, meanwhile if you find some plugin for adding tiff support to imageIO please let me know.

Comment: Vijay -- good drill down, glad you found the culprit. I'll keep my eyes peeled for an alternative TIFF impl.

Comment: Just to reconfirm the culprit, i tried resizing the image with just Graphics2D, and even then resized TIF images are not displaying in the browser, now i am 100% sure, that problem is with the Tiff implementation. Accepting your answer, since that's the only one :-)

Comment: Ah! Good find, I am glad you got to the bottom of it.