# Eclipse missing imports (javax.media.* and com.sun.media.*)

Tags: java, eclipse, jmf, javax.imageio

I have this old java applet that i need to debug, yet i have some problems with import.

```
The import javax.media.* cannot be resolved.
The import com.sun.media.* cannot be resolved
```

After some research i tried adding this external libs to the project - with no success.

1. sun-jai_codec.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsunjaicodecjar.htm
2. installed JMF2.1.1e and added the jmf.jar.

I had no luck with this... so im asking some one for a little help!

[image]

Comment: can you mention what errors you getting? or warnings?

Comment: Try refreshing your project and then cleaning it. Sometimes eclipse does not pickup changes in files. Are those two files in your .classpath file ?

Comment: Murali .. the errors are abvious (import cannot be resolved)

Comment: nikkatsa ... probably not as i downloaded them and just used "Add external JARs". I have tried clean/refresh/rebuild/reopen ... no luck.

Comment: never addexternal jars. just create a folder lib in ur project then copy the jars and add it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just build the path of your project again. Right click on the project and then select build path--->configure build path--->java build path---->libraries

select all jars and then remove and then add all jars including the jars of your project.

then click ok. then go to order and export and click all the options. then click ok.

Comment: Tried that ... no luck. Im starting to belive that the jar files do not contain the classes i am missing. How can i check what packages and classes are in jar file...

Comment: its easy just open that jar using the winrar or 7zip and extract it

Comment: thanks for your time and help! Will accept your answer anyways!

Answer (score 1):

Sheez .. this was stupid.

Its a big MESS with this old classes/jar files.
It turned out i had the wrong ones...

Found them here (links in the answer):

[Where can I download Jai and Jai-imageio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502181/where-can-i-download-jai-and-jai-imageio)