# How can I play an MP3 file?

Tags: java, jplayer

I am trying to access an [MP3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3) audio file saved in my source folder, so that I can play it in a Java program (application, not applet).

The problem I seem to be having is that I cannot import `javax.media`. I have been trying to install the Java media framework, but it gives me an error report:

> "unable to execute...".

I use JDK v7 u45 and had tried it on JDK v7 u40, but I can't seem to figure out what to do.
I tried calling

```
import javax.media.*;
```

and it returns a syntax error on the "media", claiming import is not available. Does jmf not work in Java 7?

Comment: Perhaps you want the javasound tag?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following way. It's working and also import the following classes.

```
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;

try{
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream =
        AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(
            this.getClass().getResource("<Path of relative sound file in src folder>"));
    Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
    clip.open(audioInputStream);
    clip.start();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me on OS X for mp3 files. wav works though.

Comment: doesn't work for mp3, just wav

Comment: it is for `.wav`.  `Exception in thread "main" javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input URL`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is likely that `javax.media` is not in your library. Make sure that you include the correct [JAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) file in your libraries (See [Eclipse missing imports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163524/eclipse-missing-imports-javax-media-and-com-sun-media/16163731#16163731)).

---

I previously did a bunch of searching to attempt to find out how to play audio in Java. What I found is that [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) is the easiest to use for playing MP3 files. For playing other inputs, I created a `SourceDataLine` (under the direction of [this tutorial](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J8c_PlayingSound.html)) and used that.

---

How to play MP3 music:

- [How do you play a long AudioClip?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9470148/how-do-you-play-a-long-audioclip/9470886#9470886)
- [Playing MP3 using Java Sound API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667454/playing-mp3-using-java-sound-api/5668510#5668510) (happens to be the basically the same answer as previous)
- [Playing .mp3 and .wav in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java/10237397#10237397)
  This answer suggests using `JavaFX` to play mp3's. It is the easiest method (as far as I know) for playing them. However, it has problems when used with a regular `Swing` application; this is addresed in the next answer.
- [Playing audio using JavaFX MediaPlayer in a normal Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548603/playing-audio-using-javafx-mediaplayer-in-a-normal-java-application/12548929#12548929)

Answer (score 0):

The file MP3.java is a bare bones Java program that uses JLayer to play the MP3 file specified on the command line. It plays the MP3 file in a separate thread, so you are free to perform other computation while the song plays. In order to compile and execute it, you need to put the file jl1.0.jar in your current working directory (or classpath). Instructions for compiling and executing (depending on your operating system) are included in the .java file.

Answer (score 0):

For another method that I think is fairly simple and the most up-to-date method in playing MP3 files, use the [JavaFX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX) library. A very easy way to use JavaFX is to install the [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) plugin. On that website, go to "install" at the top and follow the instruction on how to install the plugin into Eclipse. In Eclipse (after the plugin is installed), go to *File* -> *New* -> *Other*... -> *JavaFX* Project, and then your JavaFX imports will work.

The answer to the question [Playing audio using JavaFX MediaPlayer in a normal Java application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548603) (which was already linked to in another answer) was very helpful to me, and may also be helpful to you.