# Why am I getting "the import javax.media cannot be resolved"?

Tags: java, audio, media

I found a [sample code](http://java-demos.blogspot.gr/2012/11/java-code-to-play-mp3-file.html) of how to play an mp3 file. I installed the [Java Media Framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-java-client-419417.html#7372-jmf-2.1.1e-oth-JPR) as the instructions say, but then I still get this from Eclipse:

> the import javax.media cannot be resolved

on the first line of

```
import javax.media.*;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked that it is definetly added to the classpath?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse missing imports (javax.media.\* and com.sun.media.\*)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163524/eclipse-missing-imports-javax-media-and-com-sun-media)

Comment: Um truth is no. How can this be done?

Comment: @Theolodis *"Have you checked that `it` is definitely added to the classpath?"*  What is ***it***?

Comment: @IanBoyd that comment has been made 8 years ago, so I am not 100% sure, but my best guess would be that `it` refers to the Java Media Framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163524/eclipse-missing-imports-javax-media-and-com-sun-media) They solved that problem by rebuilding the project path in eclipse. You might want to try that.

Comment: Ok everything is ok now but when I run the code I get this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at AudioPlay.main(AudioPlay.java:23)

Comment: When you start the program you have to set the command argument to the path, where the mp3 is located.
`File f=new File(args[0]);` In eclipse you can do that in the run configuration.