# Option for Java Advanced Imaging(JAI)?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I was trying to read .tiff image. I got that i cant read tiff file by ImageIO.read and then read about JAI API which supports .tiff images but i am not getting JAI API to use.
So is there another option for JAI API or where can i get JAI API?

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502181/where-can-i-download-jai-and-jai-imageio

Answer (score 1):

You can read TIFF using `ImageIO.read(...)`.

There's just no plugin installed by default. You can use the plugins from JAI ImageIO, or you could try the TIFF reader from my [Twelvemonkeys](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys) project. These are both plugins for ImageIO, and allows you to use the API you already know.

Commons Imaging should also work, if you don't mind using a different API for reading.

Comment: I have just tried Twelvemonkeys , many classes are missing in that , so its not working

Comment: @swapnil7: I can assure you that all the classes are there. :-) You are probably just missing some dependencies. Are you using Maven? Or did you try with the dependencies [here](https://github.com/haraldk/TwelveMonkeys#manual-dependency-example)? PS: 3.0-rc5 is now available from Maven Central.

Comment: No, i am not using Maven

Answer (score 0):

Apache commons imaging. Slower but easier to use