# tiff image is not showing properly

Tags: java, tiff

I want to load a tiff file which is having a huge size. I changed heap size to around 800m so image is loaded but it is not shown properly:

1. This is my actual image : [image: img1]
2. This is screen shot of image which i got after loading it : [image: img2]

This is my code to load the tiff file:

```
private void browseButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser(Database.basePath);

    FileNameExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("TIF Files", "tif");
    fc.setFileFilter(extensionFilter);
    int res = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
    File file = null;
    // We have an image!
    try {
        if (res == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath().toString().substring(0,
                    file.getAbsolutePath().toString().lastIndexOf("/")));
            path = file.getAbsolutePath().toString().substring(0,
                    file.getAbsolutePath().toString().lastIndexOf("/"));
            basepath = file.getAbsolutePath().toString().replace(".tif", ".xml");
            System.out.println("path:  " + basepath);
            setTarget(file);

            // System.out.println("canoic"+file.getCanonicalPath());
        } // Oops!

        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must select one image to be the reference.", "Aborting...",
                    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }

    } catch (Exception iOException) {
    }
public void setTarget(File reference) {
    try {
        targetImg = null;
        System.out.println("in try" + reference.getAbsolutePath());
        targetFile = reference;
        byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(reference.getAbsolutePath()));
        targetImg = rescale(data);

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("in Catch");
        Logger.getLogger(HelloWorld.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    panel_1.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(targetImg));
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(label);
    panel_1.add(scroll);
    scroll.addMouseListener(this);
    scroll.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

    setVisible(true);
}
public BufferedImage rescale(byte[] originalImage) {

    TiffDecoder decoder;
    BufferedImage decodedImage = null;
    try {
        decoder = new TiffDecoder(originalImage);
        decodedImage = decoder.read();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return decodedImage;
}`
```

Comment: Kindly include code for `setTarget` method where you are loading that image

Comment: Use `ImageIO` API instead reading bytes from file

Comment: What is in rescale ?

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer. but I don't know how to use imageIo Api for reading. can You help me? @Sanjeev

Comment: Sure .. just tell me what are you trying to achieve using `rescale` ?

Comment: Looks spotless. Try dumping file name (xml?), saving originalImage, another smaller tiff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read your image using [ImageIO#read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.File))

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
```

And then set this image to ImageIcon

```
 label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
```

And you will need to put [jai_imageio.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502181/where-can-i-download-jai-and-jai-imageio) in your classpath

Comment: Thank you @Sanjeev

Comment: Your Most welcome. Please accept as answer/vote up if it did help you.