# Building an executable jar with maven+geotools jai-imageio / kakadu runtime error

Tags: maven, executable-jar, javax.imageio, geotools

Following the directions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9263950/770456)  I tried to build an executable jar for my geotools based project to distribute it to users.

Now during runtime I get the following error

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: 
Provider it.geosolutions.imageioimpl.plugins.tiff.TIFFImageReaderSpiit.geosolutions.imageio.plugins.jp2k.JP2KKakaduImageReaderSpi 
not found
```

on Runtime.

Does anybody know how to resolve this (maybe by forcing geotools to not use any native libs?)